# Constraint layout vs Relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been mostly designing my views using Relative layout as it works great when you put things positioned from the right edge, center or simply relative to each other. That would great on different screen sizes so the views are more spread.

With the introduction of constraint  layout, I find it that it is more powerfull and it achives the same purposes  while giving more flexibility.

Does that mean that Relative layout is no longer needed and can be replaced with Constraint all the time? Is there a situation where you shouldn't go constraint view and go for relative layout instead?

Thank you

Comment: Off the top of my head, I cannot think of a scenario that `RelativeLayout` can handle that `ConstraintLayout` cannot. I do not know if it is worthwhile to rewrite a lot of existing `RelativeLayout` code to switch to `ConstraintLayout`, unless you have specific reasons to do so (e.g., you're experiencing poor performance due to lots of `RelativeLayouts` in a scrolling list).

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare, I am starting a new project and I was wondering if I should use the relative layout that I currently know and used before or if I should go for constraint layout  by default or if there are cases where I need to think which one to go with. It seems from your comment that I should go for contraintlayout right away anyways since it is new code base, correct?

Comment: `ConstraintLayout` should give you greater flexibility. The cost is ~100KB more in libraries (and a corresponding increase in your method count) and less "institutional knowledge", as `ConstraintLayout` has far less written about it in places like... oh, I don't know... Stack Overflow, to pick a site at random. :-) I cannot tell you what is best for your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not much different than other layouts you are probably already using (like RelativeLayout or LinearLayout). The attributes are very similar to the ones used with Relative Layout.

This is primarily designed as a visually oriented tool. The visual editor is intended to be the main way developers interact with their layouts.

The main goal of this new layout, is to help developers create complex layouts that are optimized to rendez quickly. In fact, its aim is to reduce layout hierarchies induced by other layout types.